# Заголовок в строке не может записаться в файл, также надо записать и текст поста в файл. Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер

```
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = get('https://www.playground.ru/news').content
soup = BeautifulSoup(url, 'html.parser')
div = soup.find_all('div', class_='post-title')
for link in div:
url_links = link.find('a').attrs['href']

with urlopen(url_links) as page:
    url_links = page.read().decode()
soup = BeautifulSoup(url_links, 'html.parser')


name = soup.find('h1').get_text()
print(name)
paragraph1 = soup.find('div', class_ = "article-content js-post-item-content").text.strip()


data = {'name' : name,
        'paragraph1' : paragraph1}

with open(f'playground/{name}.txt', 'w', encoding = 'utf-8') as file:
    file.write(data['name'] + '\n')
    for x in data['paragraph1']:
        file.write('\n' + x.get_text())
```

> file.write('\n' + x.text.strip())
> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'text'

Появляется вот такая вот ошибка... Где она появляется и сами видите... Пытаюсь достать хотя бы из сайта заголовок новости, но не получается. Не знаю, что делать. Помогите пожалуйста с парсером.

Answer (score 2):

Я посмотрел исходный код данного сайта, и чтобы вывести заголовки новостей, нужен данный код:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

response = requests.get('https://www.playground.ru/news')
content = response.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')
post_titles = soup.find_all('div', class_='post-title')

for title in post_titles:
    print(title.text.strip())
```

Comment: Я понял свою ошибку... Я же не перешел по этим ссылкам... Мне нужен был заголовок не самой ссылки, а заголовок новости внутри, а потом уже сам текст поста. Я это сделал, но щас новая ошибка появилась... Но все равно большое спасибо)

Comment: Какая ошибка появилась?